# How to make an Oauth request with PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am tryin to make a `signin with Twitter` option for my webpage. Twitter says i need to make an [Oauth request](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in). Is there a class for this in `PHP`? Is there a simple `how to` lesson for amateurs like me?

Answer (score 0):

this might help you out. have a look
http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-twitter-using-php/